# Need to get users in format

Tags: database, customer

I need to get the users from my site in a specific format for a presentation.
Something like this:

```
fullname email phone
```

I dont know how to do this via MySQL because all the data is in different tables etc and its really confusing.

Any way to do this?

Comment: You can export the customer data as CSV in *System > Import / Export*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customers, as are the products and categories are structured as EAV data. Inchoo wrote [a nice article](http://inchoo.net/magento/magentos-database-layout-and-its-eav-structure/) on how it works.

This does mean your query will run over multiple tables indeed. It would probably look something like this

```
SELECT 
    `fname`.`value` AS `firstname`
    , `mname`.`value` AS `middlename`
    , `lname`.`value` AS `lastname`
    , `c`.`email` AS `email`
    , `pwd`.`value` AS `password`
    , `phone`.`value` AS `telephone`
FROM 
    `customer_entity` AS `c`
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `fname`
    ON `fname`.`entity_id` = `c`.`entity_id`
    AND `fname`.`attribute_id` = 5
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `mname`
    ON `mname`.`entity_id` = `c`.`entity_id`
    AND `mname`.`attribute_id` = 6
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `lname`
    ON `lname`.`entity_id` = `c`.`entity_id`
    AND `lname`.`attribute_id` = 7
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `pwd`
    ON `pwd`.`entity_id` = `c`.`entity_id`
    AND `pwd`.`attribute_id` = 12
LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity` AS `address`
    ON `address`.`parent_id` = `c`.`entity_id`
LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `phone`
    ON `phone`.`entity_id` = `address`.`parent_id`
    AND `phone`.`attribute_id` = 31
```

Comment: Would you know how to include the password in this? Thank you.

Comment: @J.Doe the password is hashed with MD5 so not sure if it's of any use but I made an update

Comment: Hmm, it gives an error when I try to use that but the original query doesn't.

Comment: @J.Doe ah, my bad. this should work